# How to run a command inside a variable in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I've looked online and on other Stack Overflow questions already but I can't find an answer that fixes my problem. I'm using CMake to build my application and I want to assign a variable called `MYPATH` that stores a directory. I need to get the directory by running a custom command that outputs a directory. How do I do this?

This is what I'm doing right now:
`export MYPATH=$(shell $(build_function //my//directory))`

When I try to use `$(MYPATH)` in another command it's empty.
`build_function //my//directory` outputs the string that I want `MYPATH` to be initialized as.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your command:

```
$(shell $(build_function //my//directory))
```

The first thing make does is expand the contents: make variables are introduced by `$`, so `$(build_function //my//directory)` is expanding a *make variable* with the *name* `build_function //my//directory`, which clearly doesn't exist, so expands to the empty string which results in this:

```
$(shell )
```

which doesn't do anything.

If you want to send the `$` to the shell to be interpreted, you have to double it to escape it from make:

```
$(shell $$(build_function //my//directory))
```

However this gives an error: why?  If you type the command:

```
$(build_function //my//directory)
```

at your shell prompt you'll see you get the same error: the shell's `$(...)` operation runs the command and expands to the output of that command.  In this context the shell will then try to run that output.  You don't want that, you want to get the output.  You could do this instead:

```
export MYPATH = $(shell echo $$(build_function //my//directory))
```

but this is more complex than you need: you should just write your command like this:

```
export MYPATH = $(shell build_function //my//directory)
```

Probably you should consider using `:=` instead of `=`, unless you really want to run that command every time `MYPATH` is expanded, rather than just once.